# Multiple descarga en ASP NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

Necesito descargar multiples archivos en ASP .NET, el requerimiento es ese descargar multiples archivos sin comprimirlos en un ZIP.

Muestro el codigo que he intendado.

```
 int contador_tb = grd_exportar_archivos.Rows.Count;

    int id_escaneo = 0;
    string valorx = "";
    SqlDataReader reader;
    byte[] FileBinary;
    string FileType = string.Empty;

    for (int dsk=0;dsk<contador_tb-1;dsk++) 
    {
        misdatos.conecta();
        reader = misdatos.obtener_datos_de_entero(
         "id_escaneo", int.Parse(grd_exportar_archivos.Rows[dsk].Cells[0].Text),
         "dir_abrir_documentos");
       

                reader.Read();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                FileType = reader["mime_type"].ToString();
                FileBinary = (byte[])reader["imagen"];
                Response.ContentType = FileType;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=" + reader["clv_adscripcion"] + reader["clv_adscripcion"] + ".pdf", FileBinary));
                Response.BinaryWrite(FileBinary);


        misdatos.desconecta();
        //id_escaneo = int.Parse(grd_exportar_archivos.Rows[dsk].Cells[0].Text);
        //showFile(id_escaneo);
        Response.End();
    }
```

En el codigo anterior lo que intento hacer es recorrer una tabla que ya se tiene e ir descargando archivo por archivo desde el for, y si, funciona con un un solo archivo los demás  no los descarga.

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Saluds.

Comment: Desconozco si posible hacer lo que tú quieres (quizás con un Response.Fush()). Yo CREO que no se puede de esa manera, así que enviaría un listado de los nombres de los archivos (o los ID, o cual identificador) al cliente y con javascript haría un for y descargaría la lista

Comment: Quizás esto te de ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091475/3613462 Saludos.